samsung cmd keycode one third party bluetooth keyboard
is there possible to input a left windows keycode to my bluetooth android keyboard? or does anyone know what samsung cmd button keycode is? i can not use my keyboard properly as like a windows computer's key.
I have used the key mapper app from the playstore and couldn't find a way to use my keyboard as a computer keyboard, and I have also used other android remapping apps.
